# NS_SWIFT_UI_ACTOR annotation not working with async variants of callback based objective-C methods

Tags: swift, objective-c, clang, actor, swift-concurrency

In Objective-c we can use `NS_SWIFT_UI_ACTOR` to indicate that a method or a whole class should be executed on the main actor (as we would do with `@MainActor` in Swift). This works correctly since, when invoking a method which returns a value from outside the main actor (using a Task.detached with background priority), the compiler forces us to call it using "await" (to allow for "actor switch") and, at runtime, I can see that the code is executed on the main thread.

However, when calling a callback based method on the same class (which gets an automatically "imported"  async variant, as explained [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/calling_objective-c_apis_asynchronously)) the NS_SWIFT_UI_ACTOR seems not working properly, and the code is executed on a background thread.

```objectivec
NS_SWIFT_UI_ACTOR
@interface ObjcClass : NSObject
- (NSString *)method1;
- (void)method2WithCompletion: (void (^)(NSString * _Nonnull))completion;
@end
```

```swift
Task.detached(priority: .background) {
    let objcInstance = ObjcClass()
    print(await objcInstance.method1())   <----- this is called on the main thread
    print(await objcInstance.method2())   <----- this is called on a bg thread
}
```

Comment: Fascinating question. Begs the question to what degree should `swift_attr` be dictating the threading behavior of ObjC code at all vs. simply providing Swift insights as to what the ObjC code’s threading behavior and assumptions. E.g. call `[ObjcClass method1]` from another ObjC class and it runs on current thread (which makes sense, despite Swift attributes). But I can see why calling it from Swift would (“hey, this ObjC code said it must be on the main actor, so I'll run it there”). I can also imagine why they may not have made the same assumptions for asynchronous methods, like `method2`.

Answer (score 0):

While I understand what your expectation is I don't think as of now the way actor is implemented there is any way to resolve this. Actors in swift are reentrant, which means whenever you invoke any `async` method inside actor's method/actor task, actor suspends the current task until the method returns and starts processing other tasks. This reentrancy behavior is important as it doesn't just lock the actor when executing a long-running task.

Let's take an example of a `MainActor` isolated `async` method:

```swift
func test() async {
    callSync() // Runs on MainActor
    await callAsync() // Suspends to process other task, waits for return to resume executing on MainActor
    callSync() // Runs on MainActor
}
```

But since swift can't infer from an objective c `async` method which part should run on `MainActor` and for which part actor can just suspend the current task to process other tasks, the entire `async` method isn't isolated to the actor.

However, there are proposals currently to allow customizing an actor's reentrancy so you might be able to execute the entire objc `async` method on the actor.